# How to change a table cell color based on radio button on another cell with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change a cell color in case one of the radio buttons in other cells are being clicked. I don't know why my code doesn't work

```js
<tr>
 <td>class</td>
 <td><input name="class"type="radio" onClick="enableElement1(this.form.work_permit);"/></td>
 <td><input name="class"type="radio" onClick="enableElement2(this.form.work_permit);"/></td>
 <td><input name="class"type="radio" onclick="disableElement(this.form.work_permit);"/></td>
 <td><textarea  for="work_permit"name="comments"rows="4"cols="20"></textarea></td>
 </tr>

<script>
 function disableElement() {
  text.value = ' - N.A. - ';
 obj.disabled= true; 
 
 function enableElement1(obj) {
  obj.value = '';
  obj.disabled = false;
}
function enableElement2(obj) {
  obj.value = '';
  obj.disabled = false;
}

 </script>
 <style>
 enableElement1{
 color:green;
 }
 enableElement2{
 color:red;
 }
 </style>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What cell should change and according to what click on radio button? Your code snippet also doesn't seem to work - if you may, please upload a fiddle

Comment: @Roysh I have to build a table with 4 cells ,3 of them have radio button. The 4th one changes color if radio button in one of 2 cells is clicked , or get disabled if the third radio button is clicked.

Comment: Only a `<label>` element has a `for` attribute (or an `htmlFor` property), `enableElement1`, in your CSS, is looking for an `<enableElement1>` element, not an element with a *class* of `enableElement1` (which should instead be written as `.enableElement1` in your CSS). The `disableElement` function doesn't expect an argument - from the function declaration - so passing one in is pointless, and so the `obj` reference refers to nothing.

Comment: @admin123 - your code is far from what you describe.
First, create the tables cells, then using jQuery, listen to a click event on the radio buttons and then, change background color of the table cell

Comment: @Roysh i am trying to solve it with javascript ,not jQuery.

Comment: Are you trying to apply a css rule to a javascript function???

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your current implementation:

1. the `<tr>` element is not wrapped in either a `<tbody>`. `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` or `<table>` element (the only elements of which a `<tr>` element may be a child,
2. the only element with a `for` attribute is the `<label>` element; the value of the `for` attribute should be equal to the `id` attribute-value of the element to which that `<label>` refers (a `<label>` element can refer to only one element, though an `<input>`, `<textarea>` or `<select>` element can be associated with multiple `<label>` elements),
3. Your `<table>` data doesn't appear to be tabular in nature (from the short, incomplete sample provided); if you're using a `<table>` for layout reasons then you should consider changing your approach,
4. you're using multiple functions to do the same thing, albeit with different elements; remember the **DRY** principle: **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself, and
5. you're using obtrusive JavaScript – with event-handlers (the `onclick`) in the HTML – this complicates future maintenance of your code.

With all that in mind, might I suggest an alternative:

```js
// creating a single named function to handle the required functionality:
const activateElement = function() {

  // here 'this' refers to the element to which the event-listener was bound,
  // automagically supplied from the EventTarget.addEventListener() method;

  // from the changed <input> we find the closest <tr> ancestor element:
  let textarea = this.closest('tr').querySelector('textarea'),

    // from the chnaged <input> we find the closest <td> ancestor element:
    cell = this.closest('td'),

    // from the <td> (the 'cell' variable) we retrieve the textContent,
    // and convert it to lower-case, using String.prototype.toLowerCase():
    active = cell.textContent.toLowerCase();

  // here set the custom data-* attribute-value to be equal to the
  // value retrieved from the <td> ('cell') element:
  textarea.dataset.isactive = active;

  // here we set the disabled property to the result of the expression,
  // if the 'active' variable is exactly equal to 'none' the disabled
  // property is set to true (and the element is disabled), otherwise
  // the disabled property is set to false (and the element is enabled):
  textarea.disabled = active === 'none';
};

// here we retrieve a (non-live) NodeList of all <input> elements with
// the 'type' attribute-value equal to 'radio'; we then use
// NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over those elements:
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').forEach(
  // here we use an Arrow function (because we don't need to use 'this');
  // 'input' (the argument) is a reference to the current Node of the
  // NodeList over which we're iterating:
  (input) => {
    // here we bind an event-listener to the current <input> element/Node
    // and bind the activateElement function (note the deliberate lack of
    // parentheses) as the event-handler for the 'change' event:
    input.addEventListener('change', activateElement);
  });
```

```css
/*
  here we select all <textarea> elements with a
  data-isactive attribute-value is equal to 'one':
*/
textarea[data-isactive="one"] {
  background-color: lime;
}


/*
  here we select all <textarea> elements with a
  data-isactive attribute-value is equal to 'two':
*/
textarea[data-isactive="two"] {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}


/*
  here we select all <textarea> elements; this selector
  is less specific than the preceding selectors so this will
  only apply to those <textarea> elements without a 'data-isactive'
  attribute, or with an attribute-value which is not equal to
  either 'one' or 'two':
*/
textarea {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- using valid HTML, with the <tr> appropriately wrapped in a <tbody> element, itself
     within a <table> element: -->
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>class</th>
      <!-- wrapping the <input> elements in <label> elements,
           in order that the user sees some instruction/guidance
           as to what the form control does; and removing the
           onclick event-handler: -->
      <td><label>one<input name="class" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><label>two<input name="class" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><label>none<input name="class" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><textarea name="comments"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nLe8f6r1/).

Now, the above function is written specifically to allow for additional rows to be added to the `<table>` which can call the same function, for example:

```js
const activateElement = function() {
  let textarea = this.closest('tr').querySelector('textarea'),
    cell = this.closest('td'),
    active = cell.textContent.toLowerCase();

  textarea.dataset.isactive = active;

  textarea.disabled = active === 'none';
};

document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').forEach(
  (input) => {
    input.addEventListener('change', activateElement);
  });
```

```css
textarea[data-isactive="one"] {
  background-color: lime;
}

textarea[data-isactive="two"] {
  background-color: fuchsia;
}

textarea {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>class</th>
      <td><label>one<input name="class1" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><label>two<input name="class1" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><label>none<input name="class1" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><textarea name="comments"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>class</th>
      <td><label>one<input name="class2" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><label>two<input name="class2" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><label>none<input name="class2" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><textarea name="comments"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>class</th>
      <td><label>one<input name="class3" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><label>two<input name="class3" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><label>none<input name="class3" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><textarea name="comments"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>class</th>
      <td><label>one<input name="class4" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><label>two<input name="class4" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><label>none<input name="class4" type="radio" /></label></td>
      <td><textarea name="comments"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nLe8f6r1/1/).

Note, of course, that you still have to adjust the `name` attribute of the added groups of `<input>` elements.

References:

- HTML:
- [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).
- [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).
- [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).
- [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody).
- [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea).
- [`<tfoot>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tfoot).
- [`<thead>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead).
- JavaScript:
- [Arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).
- [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).